# How to say "the last X periods"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would want to code "the last X periods".
For example, to change the background over the last twelve periods.

I am looking for a function that exists in another language (AFL): "BarCount".
Basically it uses the bar number (the first bar number being 0 and the last bar number being Bar_Index).

The script would be:

```
color1 = BarCount >= Bar_Index - 12 ? color.green : na
bgcolor(color1)
```

I bypassed my problem using this script:

```
if barstate.islast
    line.new(bar_index - 12, close, bar_index, close, color=color.green, style=line.style_solid, width = 9999)
```

It works but it is absolutely not the good way of coding it...